# Deploying to multiple specific targets in firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I have multiple firebase hostings specified in my firebase config.

What I usually do is deploy them one by one e.g.:

```
firebase deploy --only hosting:app1
firebase deploy --only hosting:app4
```

I would like to deploy multiple specific targets in one command. For example I want to deploy app1, app3 and app4. Pseudo code how that could work:

```
firebase deploy --only hosting:app1,app3,app4
```

Does firebase support something like this?

I have read documentation and experimented with various syntaxes but didn't figure it out.

Comment: It doesn't support this.  Consider writing a simple script to run the CLI as many times as you need while only executing a single command.